# How to configure a postfix mail server for multiple domains with SPF, DKIM & DMARC?

Tags: email, postfix

I have a postfix mail server that is properly configured to receive and send mails for A.com. SPF and DKIM are configured. I still have to configure DMARC. The reverse DNS is set for A.com.

I would like to host the domain B.com on the same mail server as I can't afford multiple servers and IP addresses (cf. reverse DNS).

Postfix is configured with virtual addresses so that it accept and properly redirect mails for B.com.

The problem I'm facing is that gmail rejects mails sent through the mail server with origin address B.com.

How should I configure the postfix mail server so that I can send mails as B.com ? It doesn't matter if A.com shows up in the header. I would prefer not, if possible.

Note: this is not for spamming.

EDIT: the problem was with the SPF and DMARC configuration. It is now fixed. I still have to configure DKIM.

Comment: What is the specific rejection you're getting?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Thank you very much for your help. I received an obscure reply on the first attempt, and now I receive no more replies anymore. I don't know how to debug this. Could be wrong setting of dkim.